# What is the difference between different for loops in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

Java has different `for`-loops to walk through a list. For example:

```
public void myMethod(List list) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or, we can write something like this:

```
public void myMethod(List list) {
    for (String obj : list) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or, we can use a list iterator:

```
public void myMethod(List list) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        ...
    } 
}
```

Which one is best and prevents `NullPointerException`s without any more code?

Comment: No idea what you're asking.  You seem to know the different types, just use the one you want.

Comment: Difference in terms of performance or functionality?

Comment: now you clear what i am asking still everyone clear

Comment: Well, with the first sample you have access to the index(`i`).  In the third example you can better control your iteration.  You should use the second example if none of those advantages are important

Comment: In the first one you could call `list.remove(i); --i;` but in the last one you could call `iterator.remove();`. The middle one, you can call `list.remove(obj);` but you have to `break;` right away then.

Comment: @subodh: With respect, you should turn to the Java docs which explain this very clearly: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html
Also, search SO in future because this question has been asked countless times.

Comment: [Types of for loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Kinds_of_for_loops).

Comment: An important difference is that the first loop has a bug. It should be `i < list.size()`

Answer (score 3):

Your second variant is the best (and it's essentially equivalent to your third, but less verbose). The reason it's superior is because you're looping via an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) as opposed to calling `get()` multiple times, as you would have to do with your first variant. For `LinkedList`s, for instance, `get()` is an `O(n)` operation, meaning the first snippet would be `O(n2)` whereas the second would be `O(n)`.

In the case of `null`, all three variants will throw a `NullPointerException`; you should check for `null` beforehand (or ensure that your list can never be `null`).

Comment: What abt if list=null what will second for loop will do?

Comment: @subodh See my edit; all three will produce an NPE in that case.

Comment: Try it! Write some code, make the list null and see what happens.

Comment: i do not remember but i read somewhere that if you will use second approach null pointer can be ignore

Comment: Why would you want to ignore them? They're important error messages that tell you if you're doing something illegal. As @arshajii says, you can check for null beforehand if necessary by adding an if statement (if obj!= null)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the second form is better because it's shorter. Behind the covers, it does the same as your third form.

None of the forms will prevent null pointer exceptions.